# TypeScript: Include package types in `keyof`

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been working on a [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337280/typescript-index-node-modules-namespace-types-using-template-literal) where I think the issue now boils down to the fact that the types are not included in the `keyof` operator. See the following example:

```
// my-module.ts
export const someValue = 1
export const anotherValue = 2
export type MyType = "a" | "b" | "c"


// other-file.ts
import * as pkg from "./my-module";

type ValidOptions = {
  [key in keyof typeof pkg]: typeof pkg[key]
}
```

Using VSCode's IntelliSense shows that `ValidOptions` only includes the variables, and not `MyType`.

After discovering this, it seems perfectly reasonable to do so, but I'm wondering if there is a way to include the types as well. I need the types to be able to do something like:

```
import * as pkg from "@prisma/client";

type Schemas = {
  [K in keyof typeof pkg & pkg.Prisma.ModelName]: typeof pkg[K];
};
```

Which is a map containing all the available models. I'm trying to do this because Prisma does not export a type like:

```
type Schemas = User | Log | ...
```

That lists the models out for me, and I would prefer not having to explicitly define the models myself if possible.

---

Edit: A more concrete example:

```
export const someValue = 1
export const anotherValue = 2
export type User = {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
};
export type Log = {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
};
// Not sure why it is defined like this in the declaration for prisma
export const ModelName: {
  User: "User";
  Log: "Log";
};

export type ModelName = typeof ModelName[keyof typeof ModelName];
```

Where, using the same `other-file.ts` as above, the types `User` and `Log` are not included in the definition of the `ValidOptions` type. `ValidOptions` should only contain `User` and `Log` which is why I tried:

```
type Schemas = {
  [K in keyof typeof pkg & pkg.Prisma.ModelName]: typeof pkg[K];
};
```

Comment: There's no corresponding value type for those keys; what type should, say, `ValidOptions["a"]` be?  Whatever it is, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7OLqN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please note that it is unconventional to give a generic type parameter a lowercase name like `key`.  The identifier before `in` in a mapped type is a generic type parameter, not the name of a key.  So `{[key in keyof typeof pkg]: typeof pkg[key]}` should probably be  `{[Key in keyof typeof pkg]: typeof pkg[Key]}` or even more conventionally  `{[K in keyof typeof pkg]: typeof pkg[K]}`.

Comment: @jcalz Please see my edit which I hope is a more concrete example. In your suggestion you still include `pkg.MyType` which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a solution to these kind of module aggregation problems. In a bid to avoid being explicit, is something I research on an almost annual basis but always come away empty handed...

Comment: Can you be very explicit about what you expect/want `Schemas` to evaluate to?  Is it supposed to have a key *named* `User`?  If so that's never going to happen automatically because `User` is never included anywhere as a property or string.  Type names don't get stringified.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, so `{ User: User, Log: Log }`. But you're saying this is impossible? My initial intuition is that I could use `ModelName` (which is exported by Prisma) to help infer the type names

Comment: I am indeed saying it's impossible.  That `ModelName` type isn't going to help, since its values are just the same strings as the keys.  There's no mapping from the name `"User"` to the type named `User`.  It would need to export something more useful like `const Models: {User: User; Log: Log}` (note the absence of quotes around the value types), and then you could just use `typeof Models` to be the map you're looking for.  As it is I don't know what to tell you to do other than do it manually, especially since I have no prisma expertise (although the question has no prisma tag).

Comment: @jcalz I see. The main issue is just that Prisma does not export that `Models` object which is why I was trying to do all this to define it myself. I suppose doing it manually isn't too much of a hassle anyways

Comment: So, would you like an answer saying "this is impossible"?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, think it'll be useful for anyone else looking to do something similar. I'll accept it as the answer